# How to change Picker's style

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Is there some way to change at least the color of a checkmark icon on a Picker? I have a simple picker, but I don't seem to have a way to style it a bit:

```
        Section {
            Picker("", selection: $viewModel.frequency) {
                ForEach(viewModel.frequencyTypes) { type in

                    Text(type.shortDescription).tag(type)
                 
                }
            }//.accentColor(.purple) <- this will change icon color, but its deprecated
            .pickerStyle(.inline)
            .labelsHidden()
        }
```

I managed to style the text with `.foregroundStyle()`, but I didn't succeed in changing the icon or its color on the picker, except when using `.accentColor()`, which is deprecated for this purpose.

So, is there some way to achieve this styling without creating a custom picker?

Comment: I don't think you can do this. The color of the checkmark is the "AccentColor" in the asset catalog. You can change that, but that will also change every other thing that uses the accent color.

Comment: @Sweeper Yeah I tried that already. It changes everything as you said. Its strange these simple things are not doable yet after so much time.

Comment: Also `.accentColor` modifier was useful, cause with it, I could easily override accent color on just picker and its subviews.

Comment: To be honest, I think this is a case where Apple doesn't want you to do this. They deprecated `accentColor` after all. It's their way of enforcing consistency, or something.

Comment: Have you tried [the `tint` modifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/tint(_:)-93mfq)?

Comment: I did try actually @robmayoff. To apply it on `Picker` itself. But nothing happened.